# how to create a system where store admin can upload images that would appear on a shirt/mannequin

Tags: php, image, image-processing

i have been tasked with creating an ecommerce site.  the store admin needs to be able to upload images, which would populate on a shirt/mannequin. basically there will be new shirt designs added regularly and they dont want to create a shirt to take an image of and put on a mannequin each time.

at first thought.. i was thinking the store admin would just generate a specific sized transparent png.. that would overlay a blank mannequin but i wonder if there is an easier approach.. maybe with some sort of php image functions?

any pointers would be great!

ps.  i am mainly a php / mysql developer so this is what i plan on using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you have the right approach. That's how I would implement. If you use image magic or something like that, it will use a lot of resources just to merge two images when you can create a transparent .png and use css to overlay it on the shirt.